# How can I wrap a div tag inside a svg tag

Tags: html, css, svg

Is it possible to wrap a div tag inside a svg tag?

Here's what I have so far...

```html
<div>
    <svg  style="width: 50px;height: 50px;border: solid black;">
        <div style="fill: blue;text-decoration: black">test</div>
    </svg>
</div>
```

I can't see the content of the inner div tag. Right clicking on the content in the Firefox browser shows it's there.

[image: shows edit as svg]

So are there any methods to show the div properly?

Comment: @Parco that answer is 8 years old. foreignObject works much better in browsers these days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to display a div within some SVG content then you need to wrap the div with a foreignObject tag.

Here's your markup with that foreignObject tag added. I've also corrected the CSS properties in the inner div so that they do something.

```html
<div>
  <svg  style="width: 50px;height: 50px;border: solid black;">
    <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
      <div style="background-color: blue;text-decoration: underline">test</div>
    </foreignObject>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't do this. Your html tag structure is wrong.